# How to manually reload any row in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview

I wanted to create List in SwiftUI with following requirements:

1. Each row has some detail, and `Toggle` which represents its `isEnabled` status.
2. If someone enables or disables that toggle, then based on some logic, Either I have to allow its to be enabled, OR not allow it to be enabled OR allow it to be enabled, but have to disable other object from other row.
3. I have my ViewModel and Model as below

I have my model and View model as somewhat like this

```
class MyViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published myObjArray:[MyObject]
    ....
}

class MyObject:Identifiable{
    var id:..
    var isEnabled:Bool
    var title:...
    ....
    ....
}
```

As `MyObject` is used at multiple places in project, so, I dont want to touch It.

For implementing `Toggle`, we have to provide binding, so, I created one state object in its RowView and on enable and disable of that toggle, I get its event like this:

```
struct MyRowView: View {

var myObj:MyObject

@State var isEnabled: Bool
....
....

init(myObj:MyObject) {
    self.myObj = myObj
    self.isEnabled = myObj.isEnabled
}

var body: some View {
    ....
        Toggle("", isOn: $isEnabled)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .onChange(of: isEnabled) { value in
                        self.MyViewModelAsEnvironmentObject.toggleValueUpdated()
                    }
    ....
}
```

As value of `isEnabled` changes, I am passing that to above mentioned `MyViewModel` object, where it checks for some conflicts, if conflicting, I am showing some alert, asking user to to forcefully enable this or not, if he says yes, then I have to disable row in other row, if user says no, then I have to disable this row.

Question is, How I can reload individual cell to enable or disable given toggle in given rows? If I print value directly in Row, then it is updating properly, but here `isEnabled` variable is assigned when row initiated, now its not possible to change its value from view model.

How to deal with this situation?

Comment: Consider that SwiftUI views are extremely lightweight and fast, there is almost no loss of performance when reloading the entire table view which are in fact only the currently visible rows. And it’s still faster if you use a struct as model rather than a class.

Comment: Make MyObject struct, otherwise that view model will not work - reference is not changed when you update instance in array.

Comment: This is not UIKit. You don't reload only certain rows. The entire view gets reloaded. As Varian said, these are very lightweight views.

Comment: @Yrb : Then how to reload entire view, please read the whole case.

Comment: Asperi answered that part already. The view gets reloaded when the data is changed, but only if you are using a struct. A class does not change when updating a parameter, but a struct is. That propagates down tot he view, causing the view to reload.

Comment: @Yrb The problem with reloading the list is it resets the scroll view position to start.